# Numpy is not saving csv properly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple numpy array made of floats and integers

```
array_to_save=np.array([shutter_time,int(nb_frames),np.mean(intensities),np.std(intensities)])
```

I would like to save this numpy array, appending it to an existing csv file by doing the following.

```
    with open('frames_stats.csv','a') as csvfile:
     
        np.savetxt(csvfile,array_to_save,delimiter=',')
```

However, it saves this array not as an ordinary csv file, where there were supposed to be 4 values separated by commas, but it saves each value as a new line of the file such as follows:

> 5.000000000000000000e-01
> 1.495000000000000000e+03
> 2.340000000000000000e+02
> 0.000000000000000000e+00
> 5.000000000000000000e-01
> 1.495000000000000000e+03
> 2.340000000000000000e+02
> 0.000000000000000000e+00

How can I save such a csv file properly?

Comment: You need to add more info. What are the values. What was the csv like before you append the new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply reshape your array to change you 1D array of dimension 4 to a 2D array of dimensions (1, 4):

```
with open('frames_stats.csv','a') as csvfile:
    np.savetxt(csvfile,array_to_save.reshape((1, 4)),delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas DataFrame append and DataFrame to_csv

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You are saving a one dimension array (1 column) but you are expecting the result of a 2 dimensions array with one line, so in order to have the desired result do this

```
array_to_save=np.array([[shutter_time,int(nb_frames),np.mean(intensities),np.std(intensities)]])
```

see the double square brackets